# Google Bigquery Command Line Return Limit

Tags: google-bigquery

I just upgraded the bigquery command line program, and there is now a limit to the rows being returned when I run queries. The limit seems to be 100 rows. Before upgrading, I was able to return thousands of rows. I'm using Debian. Is there a way to expand the limit of rows returned? Let me know if I can provide any more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the `--max_rows` flag. See the output of `bq help query`:

```
USAGE: bq.py [--global_flags] <command> [--command_flags] [args]
    query      Execute a query.
... 
  --max_rows: How many rows to return in the result.
    (default: '100')
    (an integer)
```